# how to change the background color of the last item added to the list view?

Tags: android, listview, background-color

I am so confused with the list list view. I want to add an specific colur to the last added row to the list, how can I do that? I have googled all internet and stackoverflow for 2 days but I can't figure out how??

I have tried

```
lv.getChildAt(lv.getLastVisiblePosition()). setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

but no success so far. I get the randowm row coloured. But I only want to colour the most recent added item.

Could someone please advice me on that.

Any comment is highly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapters have a view recycler for efficiency reasons, so this is where the "randomness" comes from...
Anyway simply create a custom adapter that tracks the index of the last row added and in `getView()` check whether the current index matches this last index:

- **If so** change the background color
- **If not** *restore* the original background color.

Watch Android's Romain Guy [explain the view recycler](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA) at Google Talks.

---

Here is an example extending ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    private int lastAdded;
    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        lastAdded = objects.size() - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T object) {
        lastAdded = getCount();
        super.add(object);
    };

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(position == lastAdded) // Red 
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
        else // Transparent
            view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(T object, int index) {
        lastAdded = index;
        super.insert(object, index);
    };
}
```

Note: This is not comprehensive. There are other ways to add data which you may or may not want to override depending the way you use the adapter.

Comment: Hi sam many thanks for your post. What I am confused here is the fact that in my class I am already extending ListActivity class. That might sound a stupid question but how do you call this class from activity?

Comment: You can cut & paste this code inside your ListActivity class or add a new file to your project named `MyArrayAdapter.java` (it must be the same name as the class). Then reference this class like any other: `setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, list));`

Comment: No trouble, it can be confusing at first. Good luck!

Comment: Hi sam, this is working perfect, but what if I want to keep the colour for those which are already coloured. I want it to keep them coloured, but now every time I add something only the last one get coloured and the other one are not coloured any more. I have commented out view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);   but still the same thing. what I really need to do , is being able to identify the elements, like having unique id for each element. Is there anyway to do that? I guess I need to open a new question on this one :)

Comment: "I want it to keep them coloured, but now every time I add something only the last one get coloured and the other one are not coloured any more." This is what the adapter should do. How are you adding data to your ListView and what are you doing to remove the colours?

Comment: perfect dude :)

Answer (score 0):

with that call `lv.getChildAt(lv.getLastVisiblePosition())` you're getting the last child that is visible AND currently on the screen.

If you want to change anything on the last item of your list you must inside the `getView` of your adapter to check `if(position == getCount()-1){  }` and do stuff to it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a customadapter for this and overriding the getView() can help you to achieve your task.

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

  // some task
   if(position == last) // once even try position == getCount() 
      {
      set background color to the view
      }
    return convertView;
}
```

here last is the last item that you will be inflating to the listview(may be an arraylist or an array or someother one that suits your requirement)